# javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement cannot be cast to com.oracle.xmlns.communications.ordermanagement.CreateOrderRequestType

Tags: java, unmarshalling

Here is the operation that I am working on. I generated WSDL and I got CreateOrderRequestType.java

But when I am unmarshalling , it is looking for CreateOrder.
How can I get CreateOrder class.

```
   @WebMethod(operationName = "CreateOrder", action = "http://xmlns.oracle.com/communications/ordermanagement/CreateOrder")
    @WebResult(name = "CreateOrderResponse", targetNamespace = "http://xmlns.oracle.com/communications/ordermanagement", partName = "CreateOrderResponse")
    public CreateOrderResponseType createOrder(
        @WebParam(name = "CreateOrder", targetNamespace = "http://xmlns.oracle.com/communications/ordermanagement", partName = "CreateOrderRequest")
        CreateOrderRequestType createOrderRequest)
        throws CreateOrderFaultMsg, CreateOrderFaultMsg1, CreateOrderFaultMsg3
    ;

public static CreateOrderRequestType convertXmlStringToJavaObject(String xmlString) {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext;
        try {
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(CreateOrderRequestType.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

            StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString);
            CreateOrderRequestType msg = (CreateOrderRequestType) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
            return msg;
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            throw new OSMException("Unable to Convert XML String to Java Objects " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }

    }

public CreateOrderResponseType createAncillariesBySoloOrderId(String soloOrderId) {
        String message = findOrderBySoloOrderId(soloOrderId);   
        //CreateOrderRequestType createOrderRequestType = null;     
        message = "<CreateOrder xmlns=\"http://xmlns.oracle.com/communications/ordermanagement\">"
                + message 
                + "</CreateOrder>"; 
        log.info("message before converting to Java Object = " + message);
        CreateOrderRequestType  createOrderRequestType = com.spectrum.order.util.OrderUtil.convertXmlStringToJavaObject(message);
        log.info("Msg Object = " + createOrderRequestType.toString());

        return osmClient.createOrder(createOrderRequestType);   
    }

My xmlString
<CreateOrder xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/communications/ordermanagement">
<msg xmlns=""><head><Client>Charter</Client><Routing>8260|1700|0090</Routing></head></msg>
</CreateOrder>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that during unmarshalling an instance of JAXBElement is returned. You can check for the returned type and handle it appropriately:

```
        Object obj = unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);

        CreateOrderRequestType msg = null;

        if (obj instanceof CreateOrderRequestType) {
            msg = (CreateOrderRequestType) obj;
        }

        if (obj instanceof JAXBElement) {
            msg = ((JAXBElement<CreateOrderRequestType>) obj).getValue();
        }

        if (msg == null) {
            throw new OSMException("Unable to Convert XML String to Java Objects ");
        }
```

And by the way, it would be better make variable `JAXBContext jaxbContext;` the class variable and initiate it not during service call, but in constructor or in some initialization method, because initialization of JAXBContext is time consuming operation and should normally happen once. JAXBContext is thread safe and making it a class variable should not affect service functionality.

Comment: On Friday, I made the change to  StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString);
   StreamSource inputSource = new StreamSource(reader);
   CreateOrderRequestType msg = unmarshaller.unmarshal(inputSource,CreateOrderRequestType.class).getValue();   and it worked. But, I am changing the intialization of JaxbConetxt as per your suggestion. Thanks.